How to verify the compatibility condition for Berry's connection?
I am reading Mikio Nakahara's Geometry, Topology and Physics. In Chapter 10, he defines the Berry's connection one-form on the $U(1)$ bundle as
$$
\mathcal{A}=\left\langle\mathbf{R}\right|d\left|\mathbf{R}\right\rangle
$$
and the compatibility condition is
$$
\mathcal{A}_j(\mathbf{R})=_j\left\langle\mathbf{R}\right|d\left|\mathbf{R}\right\rangle_j=\mathcal{A}_i(\mathbf{R})+t_{ij}(\mathbf{R})^{-1}dt_{ij}(\mathbf{R})
$$
where $t_{ij}(\mathbf{R})\in U(1)$ is the transition function between two different local sections, i. e. $\left|\mathbf{R}\right\rangle_j=\left|\mathbf{R}\right\rangle_i t_{ij}(\mathbf{R})$.
But a more common definition of Berry's connection is
$$
\mathcal{A}=i\left\langle\mathbf{R}\right|d\left|\mathbf{R}\right\rangle
$$
and the compatibility condition becomes
$$
\mathcal{A}_j(\mathbf{R})=i\ _j\left\langle\mathbf{R}\right|d\left|\mathbf{R}\right\rangle_j=\mathcal{A}_i(\mathbf{R})+it_{ij}(\mathbf{R})^{-1}dt_{ij}(\mathbf{R})
$$
Is this still the right compatibility condition with the extra $i$?
